# Find value from nested hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash like :

```
$VAR1 = {
          'x' => {
                          'Mathematics' => 82,
                          'Art' => 99,
                          'Literature' => 88
                        },
          'y' => {
                         'Mathematics' => 97,
                         'Literature' => 67
                       }
         .......
        };
```

I need to get `x, y` etc in an array(currently i don't know the values for x and y)

for eg

```
@arr = (x,y, z..);
```

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes and http://perl101.org/hashes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `keys`. If the hash is in fact a hash reference, dereference it first:

```
my @keys1 = keys %hash;
my @keys2 = keys %$hash_ref;
```